# Macro to save documents generated with word/excel automatically

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word, save

At this moment, I have a document where you enter several output from other programs, this data is converted into some statistics and graphs per person depending on who you select in a combobox (form control). this works fine at this moment.

The excel is connected to a MS Word document which displays the graphs and statistics from the person selected in the excel document.

I would like to have a button that automatically saves the individual document as PDF with a different name.

```
manual: open both documents
manual: click on the macro
macro: go to first of the combobox list (this can be done by changing output of combobox to 1)
loop
macro: open word and safe as pdf
macro: if number of people that have to be done is same as output combobox, end
macro: go to the next of the list (change output combobox by +1)
end loop
```

I have tried it for a long time but cannot manage it, I would be very thankful if somebody could help!

I use office 2010

Answer (score 1):

To save a document as PDF you just need to run this line

```
objWordDocument.SaveAs "C:\TEMP\Doc1.pdf", 17
```

The complete code to a button sabe a opened Word document is below.

```
Sub SaveWordAsPDF()
Dim wordObj
Dim objWordDocument As Object
Set wordObj = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set objWordDocument = wordObj.Documents(1) '1 is the reference index to the documente, if there are more than 1 opened you need to see wich one is the one you want
objWordDocument.SaveAs "C:\TEMP\Doc1.pdf", 17
End Sub
```